# Spring Boot - React Failed to authorize filter invocation

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, servlets, spring-security

Hi all I'm new to spring boot and react, I'm working on the simple login app **using react js and spring boot**,
whenever I try to navigate to a different API call (e.g logout,  welcome) I get the following message
**Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /welcome] with attributes [authenticated]**
I think this is something with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
looking for a proper solution

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession().and()
            //.addFilterAfter(new AuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies().clearAuthentication(true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and().httpBasic();
}
```

handleDashboard() {

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/welcome",{ withCredentials: true }).then(res => {
  if (res.data === "success") {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  } else {
    alert("Authentication failure");
  }
});
```

}

[WebSecurityConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RWXR.png)
[log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFNNT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with spring security & spring boot I was able to find the root cause and fix it, just enable the CORS at the main class file(Global CORS configuration) and will fix the above issue.

ps: even enabling CORS at its method level was not recognized properly, need to add it in the main class

```
  @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> simpleCorsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Turn out my custom filters had too high precedence in the @Order annotation and it caused interference with spring security filters. When changing to a lower precedence everything worker fine again.

Just wanted to put it out there.